# where is the best place to learn about doing intra slide transitions within powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007

i want it where some of the elements of the slide show up first and after i click, others show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Microsoft's Powerpoint documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint/CH063500711033.aspx) (the built in help is also extensive).

But please don't. I have yet to see a presentation improved by its use. People can read and listen and your slides shouldn't be extensive enough to benefit from slowly giving out tidbits.

See some of Tufte's work on Powerpoint presentations such as

- [The Cognitive Style of Powerpoint: Pitching Out Corrupts Within](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/powerpoint) (Pamphlet)
- [Powerpoint Is Evil](http://www.wired.com/wired/archive/11.09/ppt2.html) (Wired Article)
- [Powerpoint Does Rocket Science--and Better Techniques for Technical Reports](http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0001yB) (A post on his forum)
- [All of Tufte's books](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi)

Oh and never, ever use the [typewriter effect](http://www.labnol.org/tech/typewriter-effect-in-microsoft-powerpoint/12887/). Ever.